# Django: Saving a modelformset raises exception because of uniqueness constraint violation

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have a model like this (I will only paste the relevant data):

```
class Chart(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    data_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=False, blank=False)
    # one data_type will be repeated in many instances of the model

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('order', 'data_type'), )
```

When I have more than one Chart with a certain `data_type`, trying to reorder them manually becomes a big waste of time, so I decided to use a modelformset, allowing the user to only modify `order`. However, when I save the modelformset, an exception raises since the `unique_together` constraint is being violated.

Here is the formset I use:

```
class ChartOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(disabled=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Chart
        fields = ['name', 'order']


ChartOrderFormSet = forms.modelformset_factory(
    Chart,
    form=ChartOrderForm,
    extra=0,
)
```

And here is the method I use to save them:

```
@login_required
def charts_reorder(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ChartOrderFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
```

Is there a way to save them without violating the constraint that isn't modifying the orders several times, or deleting all the instances from the db and creating them again with different order?